# RxJs Observable Zip Array of Observables

Tags: javascript, arrays, observable

There is an example of using zip to combine a fixed number of observables like the following:

```
var range = Rx.Observable.range(0, 5);
var source = Observable.zip(
      range,
      range.skip(1),
      range.skip(2),
      function (s1, s2, s3) {
            return s1 + ':' + s2 + ':' + s3;
      }
)
```

My questions is what if I have an array of observables (length can be anything), how to accomplish the same like zip?

```
var arr = [observable1, observable2, ..]; //like 100 of them!
var source = Observable.zip(
      //how to put each observable here?
      function (__how to put argument here?_) {
            return /* loop through arguments*/;
      }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you can use a combination of `.apply()` and the `arguments` variable to accomplish this. Full disclosure: I have not tried this code.

```
var arr = [observable1, observable2, ..]; //like 100 of them!
var source = Observable.zip.apply(Observable, 
     arr.concat(function (varargs) { // using "varargs" purely for documentation
         Array.prototype.forEach.apply(arguments, function (observableValue) { 
            /* do something with observableValue */;
         });
     })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ES6 came out, you can simply pass an array as parameters for a function as so:

```
const arr = [ observable1, observable2, ...]
const source = Observable.zip(...arr)
```

Worked for me :D