# How to use observable.zip(array, function) with rxjava like rxjs does

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

How to use observable.zip(array, function) with rxjava like rxjs does

[RxJs Observable Zip Array of Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053384/rxjs-observable-zip-array-of-observables)

Answer (score 0):

In RxJava you have an [overload for that in zip operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip(java.lang.Iterable,%20io.reactivex.functions.Function)), that takes Iterable as input, so no need to for the rxjs solution.

```
Observable.zip(observableList, new Function<Object[], Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(@NonNull Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i do it, but it doesnt work.

`no instance(s)of type variable(s) T1 exist so that List<observable<RealmList<Article>>> conforms to ObservalbeSource<? extends T1>`

`List<Observable<RealmList<Article>>> observableList = new ArrayList<>();`

is it wrong?
how to make a observableList?

Comment: it doesn't compile you mean... it's hard to tell from your comment, where is the compile error and how exactly you've created the list. creating by new ArrayList should work. you might have mismatch with the apply function? but it is hard to tell without additional info

Comment: i want to use observable.zip(array, Observable.timer(MINIMUM_LOADING_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), function) 
is it possible to do ? how...

Comment: Not sure what do you mean exactly, please open another question, also please accept my answer if that was helpful, thanks.